# What factors could cause bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, debugging, bad-alloc

I was writing an AVL tree implementation but got an error due to bad_alloc on another platform. However, the code works perfectly for me in CS50 IDE without any warning.
In my code, I used `new` keyword to declare objects and I did deleted them after using.
My question is that what other factors could result in this bad_alloc error? And how can I solve it?

````
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class node {
    public:
    int value;
    int height;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node();
};

// freeing the dynamically allocated memory
void freeTree(node* root){

    if((root->left) != nullptr){
        freeTree(root->left);
    }

    if((root->right) != nullptr){
        freeTree(root->right);
    }

    delete root;
}

node::node(){
    height = 1;
}

int get_height(node* n){
    if(n == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    return n->height;
}

int get_balance_factor(node* n){
    if(n == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    if(n->value == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return (get_height(n->left))-(get_height(n->right));
}

// prints out the AVL tree by inorder traversal
void inorder(node* root){

    if((root->left) != nullptr){
        inorder(root->left);
    }

    cout << root->value << ' ';

    if((root->right) != nullptr){
        inorder(root->right);
    }

}

// prints out the AVL tree by preorder traversal
void preorder(node* root){

    cout << root->value << ' ';

    if((root->left) != nullptr){
        preorder(root->left);
    }

    if((root->right) != nullptr){
        preorder(root->right);
    }

}

// prints out the AVL tree by postorder traversal
void postorder(node* root){

    if((root->left) != nullptr){
        postorder(root->left);
    }

    if((root->right) != nullptr){
        postorder(root->right);
    }

    cout << root->value << ' ';

}

node* left_rotation(node* root){
    node* temp = root->right;
    root->right = root->right->left;
    temp->left = root;

    root->height = max(get_height(root->left),get_height(root->right))+1;
    temp->height = max(get_height(temp->left),get_height(temp->right))+1;
    return temp;
}

node* right_rotation(node* root){
    node* temp = root->left;
    root->left = root->left->right;
    temp->right = root;

    root->height = max(get_height(root->left),get_height(root->right))+1;
    temp->height = max(get_height(temp->left),get_height(temp->right))+1;
    return temp;
}

node* add_node(int k, node* root){
    // cout << "inserting " << k << endl;
    // BST insertion
    if(root == NULL){
        node* temp = new node();
        temp->value = k;
        return temp;
    }
    if(root->value == 0){
        node* temp = new node();
        temp->value = k;
        return temp;
    }
    else if(k > (root->value)){
        root->right = add_node(k, root->right);
    }
    else if(k < (root->value)){
        root->left =  add_node(k, root->left);
    }
    else{
        return root;
    }

    root->height = max(get_height(root->left),get_height(root->right))+1;

    // rebalancing

    int bf = get_balance_factor(root);
    // right-heavy tree
    if(bf < -1){
        return left_rotation(root);
    }
    // left-heave tree
    if(bf > 1){
        return right_rotation(root);
    }

    return root;
}

int main(){
    // initializing an avl tree
    node* root = new node();

    // handling input
    vector<string> input;

    while(true){
        string temp;
        cin >> temp;
        input.push_back(temp);

        if(cin.peek() == 32){
            cin.ignore();
        }
        else if(cin.peek() == 10){
            break;
        }
    }

    // processing input
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)input.size()-1; i++){
        string temp = input[i];
        char operation = temp[0];
        int number = stoi(temp.substr(1, temp.length()-1));

        if(operation == 'A'){
        root = add_node(number, root);
        }
        else if(operation == 'D'){
            // call delete node function
        }
    }

    // traversal
    string traversal = input[input.size()-1];
    if(traversal == "PRE"){
        preorder(root);
    }
    else if(traversal == "IN"){
        inorder(root);
    }
    else if(traversal == "POST"){
        postorder(root);
    }

    freeTree(root);

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Without seeing your code (hint, hint!) the only guess is that "another platform" has less memory available. For example, on a Linux system you can set a limit on how much a program is allowed to use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In order to get help, you need to provide details, specifically code (as @BoP) mentioned and the errors you received.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: trying to do `int * x = new int[-42]` is `bad_alloc`. Listing all possible reasons for `bad_alloc` is not very useful. Instead you should try to create a [mcve]

Comment: @Bop Hi, sorry, I just added my code

Comment: Could you update the code to work without user input, so that it can simply be started and show the described behaviour?

Comment: @gerum Actually that part is kind of essential since this is an assignment and what our program receive is standardized

Comment: @XIJING It may be essential for the programm you should write, but to get help on stackoverflow you should reduce your code so that is the smallest code that will have the same problem, a minimal, reproducable example.